# Python: Can't insert into MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

I have been trying to insert data into my MongoDB collection but it's not working:

```
try:
    client = MongoClient(uri,
        connectTimeoutMS=30000,
        socketTimeoutMS=None)
    print("Connection successful")
    print()
except:
    print("Unsuccessful")

print(client)
print()

db = client["<database>"]
collection = db["<collection>"]

print(db)
print()
print(collection)
print()

doc = {"test": "success"}

collection.insert_one(doc)
print("success")
```

The URI variable is my connection string copied from MongoDB.
Everything works fine, even the the db and collection variables print out fine until I get to the line: `collection.insert_one(doc)`

When I run, it just stops at that line and then I get a timeout error after a while. I am using the latest versions of Python and Pymongo

Comment: Does the following give the same behavior: `collection.insert_one({"test": "success"})`

Comment: @mgrollins yes it does

Comment: It sounds like you are not properly authenticated to the database. This is likely due to an improper address, user, password, or ssl setting, it's hard to know without seeing the error itself. In terms of the client, this object is created with no knowledge of the database, it's not until you attempt to insert a document into the database that the client is checked. For example `MongoClient('this should fail but does not')` will work fine, until you try to interact with the database itself, which is not really intuitive

Comment: @johnchase Are you saying that the URI is wrong? Also here is the error ```pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: No replica set members found yet```

Comment: Are you able to connect to the same database and test insert a document using _mongo shell_?

Comment: @S.Carr I am less familiar with that error. The comment about connecting to the shell is good. Also I would suggest posting the error in your question itself as well as the version of python and pymongo that you are using, and the uri - or at least how it is written without any sensitive data

Comment: @prasad_ Ok so I get this error when I try ```Please ensure that your IP whitelist allows connections from your network.``` So I'm assuming that I have to change some configuration settings.

Comment: Where is your database hosted?

Comment: @prasad_ mongodb.net

Comment: It is possible you are trying to connect to a database hosted on MongoDB's Atlas cluster. There is this note related to that: [Configure Whitelist Entries](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/). Also, please search the net with the error messages you are getting.

Comment: @prasad_ Ok. I'm going to do a bit more research with my errors and the whitelist entries and see if anything works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I resolved the issue:

1) I needed to configure the whitelist entries. (https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/)

2) I needed to get off of my Universities Wifi because they block certain things.

Answer (score 0):

There might be few things at play

1. check if the URL is correct
2. check if you write rights on the DB

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient
try:
    client = MongoClient(uri,
        connectTimeoutMS=30000,
        socketTimeoutMS=None)
    print("Connection successful")
except:
    print("Unsuccessful")



db = client["<database>"]
doc = {"test": "success"}
db[collectionName].insert_one(doc)
```